# Trying to share an mp3 with an intent but the file extension isn't included

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```java
Uri clipUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.packagename.community/raw/" + rawname);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, clipUri);
shareIntent.setType("audio/mpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

This code almost works, I can successfully send the clip to another app (dropbox for example) and everything is fine with the file except it lacks a .mp3 extension.

Comment: what are the values of the following variables (rawnames, clipUri) in debug or logs

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a question.

I am going to interpret your non-question as:

> Why, when I use a `Uri` that does not have a file extension, is a file extension not magically added by file extension elves?

That's because Android lacks file extension elves.

If you want to have a file extension in your `Uri`, you need to put one there. And, since there is no syntax that I am aware of that will give an `android.resource://` `Uri` a file extension, your choices are:

1. Share a file, instead of a resource
2. Create a `ContentProvider` that will serve up the resource via `openFile` in response to some `Uri` that does indeed have your desired file extension
3. Live without the file extension
4. Don't share the resource